# Conditional joining

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, join

I'm working on some nested views to consolidate them into one view.  in the consolidated view I have an opportunities table and a quotes table that I'm doing a full join on opportunity id so that I get all quotes, all opportunities, and the ones that are associated.

Now, the interesting bit is that I've got a table called accounts that I need to join to.  seeing as not all opportunities have quotes and vice versa, I need a good way to join to the table to get the account no matter what (and, in theory, if there is an opportunity AND a quote they **SHOULD** have the same account).  for consistency if both exist I want to use the data from the quote.

The first thing I tried was this:

```
left outer join dbo.Accounts a
on q.AccountID=a.AccountID
or o.AccountID=a.AccountID
```

Now the problem I have with that is that if I have both a quote AND opportunity it seems that it will return multiple rows, and that's not what I want.

The second try I came up with this:

```
left outer join dbo.Accounts a
on coalesce(q.AccountID,o.AccountID)=a.AccountID
```

this seems to be giving me the accurate results, but I'm curious if there's a better way to get what I want without resulting to a function in the join.

Comment: I like your second try with coalesce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that if you always have an account number you are working this backwards. You should be starting at the Acoount table and left joining to the others.

```
SELECT a.accountid, OQ.somefield, OQ.someotherfield
FROM   
    (Select coalesce (o.AccountID, q.AccountID) as AccountID,
            q.somefield, o.someotherfield
    FROM Opportunity o 
    FULL JOIN Quote q 
        ON q.opportunityId = a.opportunityId) OQ
LEFT JOIN Accounts A
    ON OQ.AccountID = A.AccountId
```

Now granted this will give you multiple rows if you have mutiple Opportunities or Quotes for the same account. And you might need some other factors in the left join to relate Opportunities to Quotes. I don't know your data to be sure.

Good for you that you are replacing the nastiness that is the nested view.

Comment: What you are trying to suggest here looks like the reversal of the sides of the OP's second query's LEFT JOIN, i.e. instead of `(O full join Q) left join A` you seem to be suggesting some sort of `A left join (O full join Q)`. I'm sure you realise that the two are not the same. (`O` and `Q`, even if they always have an associated item in `A`, may not mecessarily cover *all* the items of `A`.)

Comment: This would be the method to use if you wanted all the accounts, and the quotes/opportunities associated with them. But it will also give you accounts with no associated data.

Comment: Um, the OP is `doing a full join on opportunity id`... And the aliases in the main select need some fixing too...

Comment: @HLGEM, opportunities and quotes SHOULD always have an account, but because of the data quality here they might not, so doing a left join from a to (o full outer join q) will not present me with everything from the full outer join, and will give me accounts not associated with a quote or opportunity, and that is not what i want.  Also, i have another table that i need to join to both, i just left it out.

Comment: ok,  got some inspiration from you @HLGEM.  i moved the quote and opportunity into a derived table, selected a coalesce for the account id, then did a left join to the account table.  this seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Use the keyword DISTINCT with your query. It returns only unique entries. So your accounts should only appear once.

Comment: If a quote without a matching opportunity has a corresponding account and an opportunity without a matching quote has the same corresponding account, that account would be displayed twice no matter how you would apply DISTINCT, unless you mean to retrieve only accounts or I am missing something.

Comment: @ Andriy M DISTINCT applies to a single column.... so you might have to make it a query and then apply your DISTINCT select to that query. I'm wondering if you could do a SELECT DISTINCT a.AccountID FROM left outer join... and so on